# arm neon instruction

Tags: arm, vectorization, simd, neon

I have some code and, I want to use Neon instruction to change it, but I really don't know how to complete it... Can anyone help me?

```
void add(int n,float *a,float *b,float t) {
    int i, size = (n+2) * (n+2);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        a[i] += t * b[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using NEON intrinsics.. something like this:

```
void add(int n,float *a,float *b,float t) {
  int i, size = (n+2) * (n+2);
  float32x4_t temptt = vdupq_n_f32(t);
  for(i = 0; i < size; i+=4) {
    float32x4_t temp1 = vld1q_f32(a+i);
    float32x4_t temp2 = vld1q_f32(b+i);
    temp1 = vmlaq_f32(temp2, tempt, temp1);
    vst1q_f32(a + i, temp1);
  }
}
```

This does 4 iterations at once, and would only work when size is a multiple of 4.

Comment: thank you. But, in the code: temp1 = vmlaq_f32(temp2,tempt,temp1) maybe replace by temp = vmullq_f32(temptt,temp2); temp1 = vaddq(temp1,temp); ....is it right?